# how to substitute some lines of one file according to the line's content

Tags: text-processing

I have a file like this (this is a sample, the file contains more lines like these):

```
first line sss case-2-hello-world other words
second line other words
third line sss case-1-love-you other words
fourth line other words
fifth line other words
sixth line sss case-6-not-work other words
```

And I would like to convert it to:

```
pp:12 pme:4 plan:cpu_bind=hello mem_bind=world 
second line other words 
pp:6 pme:2 plan:cpu_bind=love mem_bind=you
fourth line other words 
fifth line other words 
pp:36 pme:12 plan:cpu_bind=not mem_bind=work
```

First, identify the lines with the pattern `sss`. Second, extract the number. Third, calculate the pp and pme: `pp=number*6 and pme=number*2`. Fourth, split the words that contain numbers in that line and assign them to `cpu_bind` and `mem_bind`. Fifth, put them together to replace the lines.

For example, I identify the line

```
first line sss case-2-hello-world other words
```

by `sss`, the number is 2. After that, I need to calculate `pp=2*6 pme=2*2`. Split the string `case-2-hello-world` into parts and assign `hello` to `cpu_bind` and `world` to `mem_bind`. At the end, I need to get

```
 pp:12 pme:4 plan:cpu_bind=hello mem_bind=world
```

replacing the original line.

Note: `sss` can be anywhere in that line but occur only one time. `sss` is only pattern can be used to identify which line need to be substituted. There are other words contain number and other numbers int the line. The pattern `case-number-cpu_bind-mem_bind` have four parts. Its order is fixed and can be spit by `-`.

Comment: plz share real time data, will be good

Comment: Please limit the rewriting of your question once correctly working answers are available. Better rethink your question and ask a new one, possible referring to this resolved post.

Comment: Can you please tell us what is you want to calculate exactly? What is the algorithm/formula? You can substitute any string you like with `sed` - you can do dynamic math based on text values with `awk` - w/ `sed` and `dc` you can generate arrays - but all you say is *something to substitute* which isn't very informative, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Anthon: It is my fault. I will try my best to express it clearly and do not edit it frequently (I am Chinese :()

Comment: When asking this type of question, please show us an example of your _real_ input data and _exactly_ what you want that to be in your output. Do not include comments or anything else in the output, we need to see the exact format you would like to have. Otherwise, people waste their time trying to help you and you change the question making their answer irrelevant.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks for your advice. I rewrite the input and output and realize that I must carefully writing my question before posting. Actually, although I change the question frequently, the essence of the problem is not changed.

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer. There are still some issues though. Will there always be only a single number in the lines? Will the string (`case-2-hello-world`) always have 4 parts or can it have more or less? Will the parts always be defined by `-`? Will the number always be the 2nd part? Will it always start with `case`? Will this string always be just after `sss`?

Comment: @terdon: There may be other numbers, but only one number after `case`. The string always have 4 parts and is split by `-`. The number in the string always be the 2nd part and start with `case`. The `sss` can be anywhere in that line and only occur one time.

Comment: OK, you have now changed the question two more times. This is enough. I am closing it as unclear. Take some time, think of the various possibilities you need us to deal with. Give us examples of different lines that will need to be recognized. Explain how a computer can understand which parts of the line you want. Think about what can change in your file and what will always be the same, think about the different combinations, ideally show us _the actual file_. **When you are sure**, [edit] the question and it can get reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is complex enough that I would use a full fledged programming language to do it. For example, in Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'if(/\ssss\s+/ && /(\S+-\d+-\S+)/){
               @F=split(/-/,$1); 
               print "pp:",
                6 * $F[1],
                " pme:",2*$F[1],
                " plan:cpu_bind=$F[2] mem_bind=$F[3]\n"
             }else{print}' file
```

Or, golfed a little but following the same idea :

```
$ perl -lpe '/\ssss\s+/&&do{/(\S+-\d+-\S+)/;@F=split(/-/,$1);
  $_="pp:".6*$F[1]." pme:".2*$F[1]." plan:cpu_bind=$F[2] mem_bind=$F[3]"}' file
```

Note that this makes a few assumptions that might not be true (but I can't know from your question):

1. It assumes that the word immediately after `sss` is the one you care about.
2. It assumes that this word will always be divided by `-` into sub words.
3. It assumes that the word will always have 4 parts, with `case` being the first, the number second, then two words that should be assigned to `cpu_bind` and `mem_bind`.

Assuming these assumptions are correct, here is the same thing as a commented script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

## Read the input file line by line
while (<>) {
    ## If this line matches whitespace (\s), then "sss", then one
    ## or more whitespace character, identify the string of interest
    ## by looking for non-whitespace characters (\S+), "-", then 
    ## numbers (\d+), then "-" and more non-whitespace characters and 
    ## save them as $1.
    if(/\ssss\s+/ && /(\S+-\d+-\S+)/){
        ## Split the word captured above into the @F array
        ## by cutting it on "-"
        @F=split(/-/,$1); 
        ## Start printing.
        print "pp:",
            ## 6 * the 2nd element in the array (the number)
            6 * $F[1],
                " pme:",2*$F[1],
                    ## The third element ($F[2]) is the 1st word
                    ## and the fourth element ($F[3]) is the 2nd word.
                    " plan:cpu_bind=$F[2] mem_bind=$F[3]\n"
                }
    ## If this line does not match "sss", print it.
    else{print}
}
```

Comment: `sss` will be anywhere but occur one time at that line.

Comment: @CodingTheLife and the "word"? Will it always be just after `sss` or do I have to look for the only word with a number?

Comment: My feedback is very slow because the web is blocked sometimes by our country. I have read your answer and fully understand it. It is very well but the first assumption is not OK. Thank you.

Comment: Some other words may contain number.

Comment: @CodingTheLife I just spent 20 minutes trying to help you and you changed your question (again). OK, I spent another few minutes finding a solution to the new one. I posted a new solution which depends on having only one word with a number. Now, you change the question _again_ and tell me that there can be many words with numbers. You don't tell me how I am supposed to guess which of these words you actually care about. So, take your time, think about your question and edit it to make it clear. We can't guess what you need and we need to know what we can depend on in your file.

Comment: Forgive me. I am really sorry. When see your answer, I realize that something is not explained very well. Then I changed it. But I can not catch up your speed for the reason that I use goagent help me to get through GFW and it often don not work. And I have to wait. After refreshing the page, your have give me the answer. The process is repeated several times. Thanks for you being patient to me.

Comment: @CodingTheLife I understand but that is why you have to think about it _before_ posting the question. You need to put thought into what you write and make it so that other people can understand you. As I said, just take your time, and when you are sure that you are giving enough information, then [edit] your question.

Comment: I have learnt a lesson from this process. Before asking question,  I should think twice and ask myself: if I am the one who want to answer, Is the information provided here clear and enough?

Answer (score 1):

In python (2.x):

```
import sys

pat = 'sss'

for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    if not pat in line:
        print line,
        continue
    case_nr = line.split(pat + ' case-', 1)[1].split('-')[0]
    print '**something about case{}**'.format(case_nr)
```

call with `python script_name.py input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But please see my new modified question.

Answer (score 1):

If using `sed` is ok:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)sss case-\([0-9]*\)-.*/something about case\2/' input.txt
```

Comment: I think it is not easy or possible to use arithmetic operations and string concatenation for generating strings for different cases in sed statement..

Comment: @CodingTheLife There is no arithmetic, just cutting the right value into a buffer. This `sed` statement takes your input and generates the requested output. Just try it out please. The first version of this, had the `**` around the strings, now it is a you ask.

Comment: Please see my new modified question:)

Answer (score 0):

According as I have understand explanation:

```
 sed "/sss/{s/case1.*$/$case1;s/case2.*/$case2;s/case3.*/$case3}"
```

but if you need to replace full line or, in the opposite, to remain words in the end just ask in comments - it's very easy to provide.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't express my question clearly. Please see my new question above.

Comment: @CodingTheLife If you wants to replace the number substitute `case1` by `[0-9]`. If you wants to do some calculations with the number better use `awk`. I can provide the script just you suply with exact example.